# Rich text box rounded corner selection highlight

Tags: richtextbox, selection, highlight

I've been searching around the web on how to code syntax highlighting text boxes and I've got most of it working. But I've always loved mac's xcode selection highlight which has rounded corners. Recently I saw this type of selection highlight in inType text editor. This image explians much better the effect I want to have in my rich text box.

its hard to explain in words so you can check out an image here http://www.blackackle.com/corner.jpg

Any ideas on how to get this result? I'm coding on C# .NET but if the solution requires any other language it doesn't matter.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll thing you'll need to implement your code editor from the ground up, similar to what the Mozilla Labs team did with the their [Bespin project](https://bespin.mozilla.com/). As they illustrate at a [talk](http://code.google.com/events/io/sessions/BespinOpenWeb.html) at the latest Google IO conference, they use the canvas tag, which is a part of the new HTML 5 standard, to implement a code editor from the ground up, enabling them to among others create their own scrollbars etc. I don't know if you're implementing a web - or windows app, but using a similar technique as the Mozilla Labs team did, you could implement something similar in C# with technologies such as WPF or Silverlight (that also has Canvas placeholders).